# RTX 3070 TI not recognized

Tags: gpu, nvidia-rtx

I just bought Zotac Gaming GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Trinity OC NVIDIA 8 Go GDDR6X, but when I plug it to my mother board, with the PCI-express cable, it doesn't start. The GPU fans are not running and black screen, PC not booting.

My specs :

ASUS Z390 A PRO
LDLC EC-500 Quality Select 80PLUS Bronze 500W
Intel i9 9900 KF

I was wondering if my power supply was too low (it is 500W only), could this be the problem ?

Or could this be because my power supply dosen't have 2x pcie 8-pin or something ?

Here is a picture of the plugged GPU (the LED is on, but that's all) :

[image: my RTX 3070 TI]

Many thanks

EDIT :

I finally bought a PSU with 750W Gold and it works perfectly now! I plugged both the 8-pin sockets to the GPU and the vents started running, everything is fine now, thanks for help

Comment: Googling I see 600W,I see 650W power supply required ..

Comment: Plug a connector into the second GPU power socket.

Comment: Their site says 750W PSU, but it draws 310W. Intel says 95W for the processor. So 500W might be fine depending on other power draws in the system but the lack of dual 8-pin PCIe might cause issues if the bundled dual molex-8 pin adapters are used. I have heard rumors of things melting. ( https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/zotac-gaming-geforce-rtx-3070-ti-trinity-oc#spec )

Comment: @Yorik the motherboard could be another 15W with all the ethernet, PCH, and other peripherals, another ~4W for the memory (per stick), then 5-10W per HDD/SSD and then 150W worth of stupid annoying LEDs so you can be seen on the other side of the Atlantic on a foggy night. It all adds up so after the CPU and GPU I'd guess at 50-100W worth of "other" to be safe. Then you have to take off 20% from the power supply rating to deal with temperature derating under heavy loads in hot rooms... Better to go a little over with your power supply than a little under and end up with an unreliable supply.

Comment: @Mokubai agree 100%

Comment: Also, I note that their 750W PSU recommendation is about 600W at 80% efficiency.

Comment: I'd always assume a manufacturer's published PSU recommendation to not get them sued if you buy the cheapest one you can find. Safety [CYA] margin.

Comment: @ValentinL. For your next PSU, it might be worth getting a gold-rated one. It will give out a bit less heat than a bronze-rated one with the same load and so very likely be able to run its fan slower, so a bit quieter too.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! :)

Comment: `Or could this be because my power supply dosen't have 2x pcie 8-pin or something ?` The GPU has two power sockets. You've only plugged one in. So yes.

Comment: Just so you know, I also tried to plug both the PCI-E 6+2 slots to the GPU, but the result is the same. I think my PSU is not powerful enough, this could also be the cause of the problem (no boot, no signal) if I understand correctly?

Comment: Note that simply adding a Y adapter/splitter to your single existing power cable so that you can plug "something" into both GPU sockets is a BAD idea!  There are two plugs because the GPU draws more power than a single cable can safely deliver.  I've seen a lot of "melted GPU" complaints that were attributable to this.   (OP didn't indicate that they were attempting this - mostly just a PSA)

Comment: Doesn't matter what wattage the PS is if it isn't getting there... I see a 7/8 pin set not attached to its 6 pin. What's up with that? Is there another 6 pin somewhere? Attach that and it becomes your second 8 pin. Or your card takes one 6 and one 8? You're lucky it doesn't need *three*. Which any power supply you do buy should have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are we looking at two 8-pin sockets, only one of which is connected?
If so, then that's why. You need the other 8-pin. 6-pin can carry 75W, 8-pin 150 [& the PCI slot another 75]. You can fake it with 6>8-pin converters, though it might be crashy under high load, but really you need 2x8-pin.

A quick Google tells me that GPU can draw 320W so 6-pin won't be enough at full draw. A 500W PSU, even with 2 8-pin supplies, isn't powerful enough.

Zotac themselves recommend 750W for that card - https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/zotac-gaming-geforce-rtx-3070-ti#spec

Comment: Was going to comment about this but you beat me to it. Both 8-pin connectors on the GPU need to be attached.

Comment: Thank you! so I guess I need to buy a new Power Supply bloc with the required connectors ? I didn't know power supply blocs wouldn't be compatible with some cards

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid you're trying to match a power-hungry card with an entry-level PSU right now.

Comment: Keep in mind that for testing purposes only, you can bridge a couple of cables on the unpopulated connector. This will make the GPU think that the second connector is plugged, and it will startup. I do not want to go into further details, which you can find online, because this is inadvisable and you should not do it unless you know what you are doing.